# find multiple strings using str_extract_all

Tags: r

I have a list of strings as follows:

```
tofind<-c("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd")
```

I also have a vector as follows:

```
n<-c("aaabbb","aaa","aaacccddd","eee")
```

I want to find all matches of my `tofind` string so that the output should be:

```
aaa,bbb
aaa
aaa,ccc,ddd
```

I think I can use `str_extract_all` but it doesn't give my the expected output

```
library(stringr)
sapply(n, function(x) str_extract_all(n,tofind)
```

How do I get the expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a single regex:

```
tofind <- paste(c("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"), collapse="|")

str_extract_all(n, tofind)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "aaa" "bbb"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "aaa"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "aaa" "ccc" "ddd"
>
> [[4]]
> character(0)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The `str_detect` function can help here

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
library(stringr)

tofind <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd")
n <- c("aaabbb", "aaa", "aaacccddd", "eee")

sapply(n, function(x) tofind[str_detect(x, tofind)], USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "aaa" "bbb"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "aaa"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "aaa" "ccc" "ddd"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> character(0)

# or the tidyverse alternative...  
n %>%
  map(function(x, y) y[str_detect(x, y)], tofind)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "aaa" "bbb"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "aaa"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "aaa" "ccc" "ddd"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> character(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R

```
sapply(n, function(x) tofind[sapply(tofind, function(y) grepl(pattern = y, x = x))])
#$aaabbb
#[1] "aaa" "bbb"

#$aaa
#[1] "aaa"

#$aaacccddd
#[1] "aaa" "ccc" "ddd"

#$eee
#character(0)
```